# JMX output in graph format

Tags: jmx, splunk, java-melody

Is it possible to show JMX Bean output in a graph?
I am currently using Javamelody but it doesn't show JMX Bean output in graph. Tried using Splunk but I have no idea, how does it gets integrated with tomcat server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net) ? That will [chart JMX variables](http://visualvm.java.net/mbeans_tab.html).

Comment: Is there anyway to integrate it with Javamelody?

Answer (score 0):

Integration is offered by [Splunk Add-on for Java Management Extensions](http://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/2647)